# Finding all subsequences from dictionary

Tags: algorithm

In a program I need to efficiently answer queries of the following form:

Given a set of strings A and a query string q return all s ∈ A such that s is a subsequence of q
For example, given A = {"abc", "aaa", "abd"} and q = "abcd", "abc" and "abd" should be returned.

Is there any better way than iterating each element of A and checking if it is a subsequence of q?

NOTE: I have STRIPS planner or automated planner in mind. Each state in STRIPS planner is a set of propositions like {"(room rooma)", "(at-robby rooma)", "(at ball1 rooma)"}. I want to find all ground actions applicable to a given state. Actions in STRIPS planner basically consist of two parts, preconditions and effects(which are not really relevant here). Preconditions are set of propositions needed to be true to apply an action to a state. For example, to apply an action"(move rooma roomb)", its preconditions, {"(room rooma)", "(room roomb)","(at-robby rooma)"} must all be true in the state.

Comment: yes there is - you can build up a FSM from your set `A` and just put `q` through it and count/remember the final-states you encounter - it's basically the lexer stuff from parsing - is this homework or a job-interview question? ;)

Comment: _iterating each element of `A` and checking if it is a sub-sequence of `q`_ is not a bad idea. Its complexity is `O(n2)`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Querying would definitely be faster with FSM, but I guess it would be too costly to build it.

Comment: @user3127171 you wanted "efficiently answer" - the brute force approach is quite bad for that - but it's your call

Comment: @CarstenKönig I meant to say that it might be computationally too expensive to build an automaton from a set A (if it's DFA). If it's NFA, I guess it's still a little expensive to query, but might be better than my brute force approach.  Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

If your set *A* is large and you have many queries, you could implement a [trie-like structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), where level *n* refers to character *n* in a string. In your example:

```
trie = {
    a: {
        a: {
             a: { value: "aaa"}
        },
        b {
             c: { value: "abc"},
             d: { value: "abd"}
        }        
    }
}
```

That would enable you to look up matches in a forked path through the trie:

```
function query(trie, q) {
    s = Set();

    if (q.isEmpty()) {
        if (trie.value) s.add(t.value);
    } else {
        s = s.union(query(trie, q[1:]));

        c = substr(q, 0, 1);
        if (t[c]) {
            s = s.union(query(t[c], substr(q, 1));
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Efectively, you will generate all 2^*m* subsets of the quesy string of *m* characters, but in practice, the trie is sparse and you end up checking fewer paths.

The speed payoff comes with many lookups. Building the trie is more costly than doing a brute-force lookup. But if you build the trie only one or have a means to update the trie when you update the set *A*, you wil get a good lookup performance.

The actual data structure for the trie nodes depends on how many possible elements the items can have. In your example, only four letters are used. If you have a limited range of "letters", you can use an array. Otherwise you might need a sort of dictionary, which might make the tree quite big in memory.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Actually, I came up with this idea as well, but I was wondering if generating all 2^m subsets is a good idea. After reading your explanation, however, I could finally convince myself that this is a way to go.

Comment: Judge according to your needs. If your set is small and lookups not frequent, the naive way might be okay. The idea of the trie is to cut many of the possible 2^m paths short.